# website url redirecting for bad urls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website URL is: [gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx](http://gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx).

When we type [gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/welcomepage.aspx](http://gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/welcomepage.aspx) or [gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/index.php](http://gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/index.php)

it is redirecting to [gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx](http://gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx).

How to show error page for [www.gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/index.php](http://www.gitam.edu/welcomepage.aspx/index.php)

Comment: should enable 404 error in control panel and add a custom page if possible

Comment: iam using windows server 2012 and in iis 8 i configured  .net error pages 404

Answer (score 0):

[See the article on it here. It is exactly what you need](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)